# .innerHTML does not modify content in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched other similar questions/answers but no one seems to work for me.
I've tried every single combination (text, innerHTML, jQuery, html) to make it work without success.

Javascript:

```
if (store.indexOf(nome) > -1) {

if (righe+incrementi < 30) {

    posizionamento = store.indexOf(nome);
    var incrementa = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity'+posizionamento).innerHTML);
    incrementa ++;
    document.getElementById('quantity'+posizionamento).innerHTML = incrementa;
    incrementi = incrementi+1;

    var settam = document.getElementById('count').innerHTML;

    var tipo = document.getElementById(posizionamento).getAttribute('data-tipo'); 
    if (tipo === "water"){
        settam++;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = settam;
        alert(settam); }}}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="conteggio">
<div class="titoli">Elements:</div>

<span style="display: none" id="counttxt">
    <span class="conteggio">Count</span>
    <span class="count" id="count"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

I'm getting mad with that, the alert work correctly (shows the right int) but the innerHTML does not change nothing, meanwhile the other works correctly (incrementa ++; [...].innerHTML = incrementa;)
Tested in chrome and safari. 
In firefox it change, but after I close the alert it set back the "value" to the previous "value".
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is your HTML code like? So we can take a look at your `count` element

Comment: Edited right now!

Comment: I adore questions starting with `else if` :D :D makes me wonder ♪ ;) please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Happy to be funny. Many thanks for the (2) downvote for a formality, very "human" treatment to a beginner!

Comment: @FlaivoLuminolZanardi I think the code has a style="display:none" that's making the innerHTML not display. I hope that's all there is to it. Also, ignore the sarcastic comments and don't be discouraged to post again. If someone doesn't help many others will. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove style="display: none" from

```
<span style="display: none" id="counttxt">
```

Try

```
<span id="counttxt">
    <span class="conteggio">Count</span>
    <span class="count" id="count"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: It's not that, when this function run display will be inline. The count inside the span it's visible when I try to change it!

Comment: Can you provide code that doesn't error? When I try the code in your question there are many errors like "quantity" tag doesn't exist, store is not declared, etc. When I clean up the code provided I have no problems. At this time I think  the innerHTML is working correctly and you have code somewhere else that's setting it to something else.

Comment: Exactly, shortly after that post I've try it. The span it's set by a function, that function it's called before (in the order of the js file it's loaded before) and the innerHTML seems to do nothing. It was a silly problem indeed!